# clearing past life karmas with people

Tags: philosophy, karma, astrology, spirituality

What are the ways to clear past life karmas with parents & other people? How to forgive people & accept them regardless of your suffering?

I'm wanting to know the **tangible ways** of working with my past life karmas.
For example will this kind of imaginary remedy work? 
If I pray God to clear my past life karmas with specific people, will it work ? If so, please tell me the name of the Hindu God temples that I must visit ? 
If it’s possible, should I visit temples with those specific ppl or it’s ok if I can imagine them, ask for forgiveness, acceptance when praying?

Comment: Do u want to know whether thru ur own efforts can u erase past karmas or others? or ur question is not that?

Comment: @Rickross, yes I want to know what kind of efforts do I need to put to clear karmas in this life;

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very difficult , i will try to answer as i can.

First , it cannot be an unilateral vision, whatever happened . Karma is produced by everybody , everyday.

The bondage of an individual self consists in the limitation of its powers of knowledge and action. It is called “*Svarupakhyati*” because is due to the individual ignorance of the real nature of the self.This limitation necessarily involves desire. It is the root of all actions or *Karmas* and is called *Karmamala.*

According to the teachings of the *Upanishads* ,  the three functions of the Brahman are called **creation, preservation and destruction.**(*Sristi,Sthiti,Samhara*) In the *Trika* system and the *Agamic* one , there are two other stages called *Tirodhana* and *Anugraha* which are **obscuration** and **grace.**

It is spoken of as *Karma* because it is the primary cause of all kinds of its associations and experiences.It is the **self-arrogation** of the individual which is responsible  for the **attachment** of merit and demerit.

***Self-arrogation is thus the soil without which the seed of Karma cannot grow.***

*Karma* is not associated with the body but with the limited self and therefore it is not destroyed with the destruction of the body.The state of *Karma* when it is about to assert itself it is called maturity or *Phalonmukhata* . The usability of *Karma* in the latter state can be destroyed by counter action such **charity, austerity penance and knowledge** if they be done long before the stage of *Phalonmukhata.*

Destruction of *Karma* is one of the most essential condition of the liberated soul , but not the only one : according to the *Trika* system can be acquired by **Shiva’s Grace** when the *pashu* , the human, realizes his oneness with the *Universal Self*.

If *Karma* of others afflicts us , wrong decisions of parents of others apparently destroy our life, our decisions, it is the real moment when we need to get the fruits of our past devotion , the moment when we can  satisfy our self with Rudra , understanding that this life is not the ultimate reality and we will never be truly free without *Moksha*, the real knowledge of the self, **Shiva**.